# Idle GPU between inferance when using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

### Question:

There seems to be a slight idling time between inferences when using keras with a tensorflow back end shown in nvprofiler. The attached image of my terminal shows that keras takes ~80ms for each inference, while a check with nvprofiler shows that the calculation takes 62ms (including host to device copy and device to host copy) and it is basically idling the rest of the time. In addition, there is a difference in the average inference time (between 80 ~ 150ms) each time i run the code below and i am unsure why that is the case.

1. I was wondering if there is any way to speed up the inference time
   by reducing this idling time.
2. Another question is am i missing some steps like clearing the GPU
   memory that cause the difference in inference time.

The input to my model is (1,800,700,36) which is basically a point cloud in a voxelized grid. The output is 2 matrix (1,200,175,1) & (1x200,175,6).

### Setup:

1. Ubuntu 16.04
2. Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820X CPU
3. GeForce GTX 980
4. Python 2.7
5. Tensorflow 1.12.0
6. Keras 2.2.4

### Attempts reduce inference idle time

1. Allowing the memory to dynamically grow on the GPU

   `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True`
2. Limit the maximum gpu usage

   `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.66`
3. Set learning phase to test

   `keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)`
4. Change batch size to None and step size to 1. Changing batch size to 1 and step size to None makes inference slower

   `model.predict(input_data, batch_size=None, verbose=1, steps=1)`

### Terminal Output

[Output of keras verbose in terminal that shows each step taking ~80ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eHm0.png)

[Same code, Output of keras verbose in terminal that shows each step taking ~100ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQOff.png)

### Images of NV profiler

As NV profiler is very long, I have split the image to 3 parts and have minimized process threads that are not running anything during that period. The images shows that the actual calculation takes ~60ms and the GPU is basically doing nothing for 20ms. This idle changes from run to run and sometimes it goes up to 70ms.

[Part 1, time between the green lines is not doing anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbxBS.png)

[Part 2, time between the green lines is not doing anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDu7I.png)

[Part 3, time between the green lines is not doing anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5NZo.png)

### Code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
from keras.models import load_model


    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.66
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)
    set_session(sess)  
    keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)

    losses = {
        "binary_crossentropy" : "binary_crossentropy",
        "huber_loss" : losses.huber_loss,
    }


    model = load_model('/home/louis/pixor/models/city_trainin_set/pixor_model_10_0.008.hdf5', custom_objects=losses)
    obj = massage_own_label(base_dir,data)

    input_data = obj.process_input_data(obj.load_pc_data(0))

    for i in range(0,100):   
        out_class, out_labels = model.predict(input_data, batch_size=None, verbose=1, steps=1)
```

Comment: Do you have gpu persistence ? `nvidia-smi` will tell you the value. `nvidia-smi -pm 1` will turn it on.

Comment: @Demi-Lune Thanks for your reply. I tried it with and without gpu persistence, and there seems to be no difference. According to nvidia, the persistence mode is legacy code and has been replaced by persistence daemon. However i am unable to run the persistence daemon `nvidia-persistenced --user foo` even with super user permission.